# how can i bridge my LAN port to batman-adv?

Tags: 12.04, networking

On Ubuntu 12.04 I have my Laptop connected to and part of a batman network. So my Laptop is meshing with the net. The script I used is [this](http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/wiki/Eigenen_Rechner_in_das_Freifunk-Netz)

How can I install a bridge, that will allow another host laptop to get internet through my Laptop?

I tried this:

```
service network-manager stop

batctl if add eth0
apt-get install bridge-utils
```

I added this in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.116.123.123
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 5
    bridge_stp no
```

then `ifconfig` sais

```
br0 Link encap:Ethernet Hardware Adresse 00:a0:d1:a9:db:da 
rubo78: inet Adresse:10.116.123.123 Bcast:0.0.0.0 Maske:255.255.255.255

bat0 Link encap:Ethernet Hardware Adresse 6e:8a:8f:f2:82:e3 
inet Adresse:10.116.2.250 Bcast:10.116.255.255 Maske:255.255.0.0
```

ifup br0

batctl if

```
eth0: active
wlan0: active
```

but I get no network on the host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:
http://freifunk.in-kiel.de/wiki/Eigenen_Rechner_in_das_Freifunk-Netz

main commands:

```
  ifconfig bat0 up promisc

...

  ifconfig eth0 up promisc

  brctl addbr br-freifunk
  brctl addif br-freifunk bat0
  brctl addif br-freifunk eth0

...

  dhclient br-freifunk
```

and to stop it:

```
  brctl delif br-freifunk bat0
  brctl delif br-freifunk eth0
  brctl delbr br-freifunk

  ifconfig br-freifunk down
  ifconfig bat0 down -promisc
  ifconfig eth0 down -promisc

  batctl if del $IFACE
```